# Multiple CUDA versions on machine nvcc -V confusion

Tags: cuda

I used to have cuda-7.0 installed on my machine and later un-installed cuda-7.0 and installed cuda-8.0. When I go to my /usr/local folder I see the following folders:

```
/bin/
/cuda/
/cuda-7.0/
/cuda-8.0/
/etc/
/games/
/include/
/lib/
/lua/
/man/
/MATLAB/
/sbin/
/share/
/src/
```

I guess I'm confused since the /cuda/version.txt file says it is on cuda-8.0, but when I type:

```
$ nvcc -V
```

it reports that I'm using version 7.0:

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2015 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Mon_Feb_16_22:59:02_CST_2015
Cuda compilation tools, release 7.0, V7.0.27
```

What still puzzles me is that even if I do:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/cuda-8.0/bin
```

after I type `$ nvcc -V` , it still outputs version 7.0.

Edits:

```
$ which nvcc
/usr/local/cuda-7.0/bin/nvcc

$ echo $PATH
/home/arturo/torch/install/bin:/home/arturo/torch/install/bin:/home/arturo/torch/install/bin:/home/arturo/torch/install/bin:/home/arturo/torch/install/bin:/home/arturo/torch/install/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/local/cuda-7.0/bin
```

Comment: Do `which nvcc` and `echo $PATH` and edit the output of those into your question and I'm sure someone will be able to explain it for you. It's likely that the CUDA 7 path is still in your PATH and it precedes the CUDA 8 path. You may be able to "fix" it with `export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-8.0/bin:$PATH` but you should really clean up things properly.

Comment: Edits added. Seems like they're pointing to 7.0 ...

Comment: Your PATH variable doesn't show CUDA 8 path at all. Do the export  command I gave in my previous comment then check nvcc version.

Comment: Seems to work and now and is pointing to the 8.0 version. Thank you.

Comment: @arturo, please add a short answer describing what you did to fix this. It is perfectly OK to answer your own questions, and the answer will help others and make your question easier to find in search.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Solution as suggested in the comments:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-8.0/bin:$PATH
```

The problem was the ordering of `$PATH`, that my previous command had the `=$PATH:/usr/local...` instead of `=/usr/local....:$PATH`

Answer (score 20):

I faced a similar issue after upgrading from cuda-8.0 to cuda-9.2.

Solution is to change the following in *.bashrc* file:

```
export CUDA_HOME="/usr/local/cuda-9.2"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/cuda-9.2/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/cuda-9.2/bin:$PATH"
```

Comment: Shouldn't `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` be inside the quotes?

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution provided by [Brian Hourigan](https://medium.com/@brianhourigan/if-different-cuda-versions-are-shown-by-nvcc-and-nvidia-smi-its-necessarily-not-a-problem-and-311eda26856c)

Use `dpkg -L nvidia-cuda-toolkit` to see where your cuda is installed to. Assuming it is installed at `/usr/local/`, which usually is the case, do the following:

```
nano ~/.bashrc

export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-X.X/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}$

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-X.X/lib64${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}}
```

where X.X is the version of cuda

overwrite the file using commands below

```
ctrl + o

enter

ctrl + x
```

refresh your bashrc by doing

```
source  ~/.bashrc
```

confirm your NVIDIA's CUDA Compiler is correct by doing

```
nvcc --version
```