# Install CUDA 8 and CUDA 9 in windows

Tags: windows, parallel-processing, cuda

Just checking if I am able to install 2 different cuda version on windows.

**System config:**

`Windows 10 pro`
`GTX 1080Ti`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is only one requirement, that one needs to satisfy in order to install multiple CUDA on the same machine. You need to have the latest Nvidia drivers, that is required by the highest CUDA that you’re going to install.

**Environment prerequisites**
Nvidia [latest driver](https://developer.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/9.2/Prod2/network_installers/cuda_9.2.148_win10_network) and at least 2 different CUDA libraries.

**Other settings**
Set the environment variables.
Create a script that changes the `PATH` variable for fast switching.
Then the shell will execute the CUDA version you have set in the path.

For more instructions, check [here](https://blog.kovalevskyi.com/multiple-version-of-cuda-libraries-on-the-same-machine-b9502d50ae77) 
and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40517083/multiple-cuda-versions-on-machine-nvcc-v-confusion).

Comment: Do you have instructions for Windows system. Above information is for Linux machine.

Comment: It's the same. Just having the latest driver. The other information is for fast switching

Comment: The stack question is for windows (second link)